# Can't get notification from firebase

Tags: firebase, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am trying to add firebase library in xamarin application. but my application has the following problem:

1. when i run my application is get notification perfectly.
2. but when my application is come in background at first time it does not get any notification.
3. and then my app is come again in foreground it get notification perfectly in every condition.

i am also search about this and i found that my app is autometically go in force stop mode.

I use plugin.pushnotification 1.3.0 library for my app

Answer (score 0):

you have to implement **FirebaseMessagingService** to get notification from firebase in background

Comment: i get notification in background perfectly.but the problem is this my app is automatically come in force stop mode when first time it come in background mode